# What is the proper way of making a copy of a record before updating it in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm new to writing SQL procedures (in this case SQL Server) and I'm trying to execute two statements in one begin, an INSERT and an UPDATE. What I'm trying to do is make a copy of existing phone number and id to the phonelist_log table and then update the existing record. I'm not sure if this a proper way of doing it or if the triggers on INSERT can do this. Please advice how to solve the multiple DML statements in one and or I should be looking on doing this using triggers. Thanks in advance.

```
DECLARE @id VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @phone VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @newPhone VARCHAR(10)

SELECT @phone = phone from phonelist where id = @id
IF (@phone IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO phonelist(id,phone) VALUES (@id, @newPhone)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO phonelist_log(id,phone) VALUES(@id,@phone)
       UPDATE phonelist SET phone = @newPhone where id = @id
    END
```

Comment: but if what you've shown works then is there actually a problem? You can put as many statements in a `begin/end` as you like.

Comment: there isn't anything wrong with your query right now, except you might want to wrap that in `BEGIN TRAN ... COMMIT TRAN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you have mentioned is fine, you can perform multiple DML operations in one begin/end but make sure to use in **Transaction** whenever you are performing multiple DML operations.

The trigger is also one of the option to archive this but as per my opinion above approach is better.

Another good option is to use **CDC - Change Data Capture**( SQL server inbuild feature) for change tracking. You can enable CDC on the whole database or for a particular table in your case you can enable it on phone list table. This will track all your table changes (insert/update/delete) in a separate table. For more details on CDC -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/enable-and-disable-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017